# C++ reinterpret_cast of std::shared_ptr reference to optimize

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, reinterpret-cast

You have two classes `Animal` and `Dog` (where `Dog` inherits from `Animal`), and you have a situation where you are often expecting an animal but are sending an instance of a dog.  In my particular case, I am often casting a strong pointer (`std::shared_ptr<Dog>`) to an animal-expecting function (`std::shared_ptr<Animal>`).

If we accept that we can make the function parameter a reference (`std::shared_ptr<Animal>&`, avoiding arguments as to why you should not have strong pointers as reference parameters because of concerns of changing ownership with threads), I assume we would be safe memory-wise to cast a `std::shared_ptr<Dog> dog` using `reinterpret_cast<std::shared_ptr<Animal>&>(dog)`, right?

And if so, what could come up other than threading issues; such as that of the reference counting variety?

To be clear, the intent is to have a solution that would be used in many instances, where casting once isn't really a viable solution.  It's more the issue that there are many objects that would have to be cast.  Also, ignoring that `std::unique_ptr` may or may not be a better solution.

To add a final requirement - using plain pointers would not allow me to change the original `std::shared_ptr` in the case of a generalized serializer class function that is virtual and thus cannot be made templated.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use [`static_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast)?

Comment: To avoid overhead. In my particular case, this is something where code is being generated. Or in the case of building a custom copy constructor where you have multiple layers of inheritance and need to keep casting upwards.

Comment: Are these classes related by inheritance?

Comment: @Steve Yes, adjusted :P

Comment: If you are expecting an Ainimal but you get a Dog, why the casting? A Dog is an Animal.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am often casting a strong pointer (`std::shared_ptr<Dog>`) to an animal-expecting function (`std::shared_ptr<Animal>`).

There is no need to cast (i.e. *explicitly* convert). Shared pointer to derived type is implicitly convertible (1) to a shared pointer to base class.

> (a) If we accept that we can make the function parameter a reference

We can only accept this assumption if a few requirements are met. Firstly, the function must not store the referenced argument beyond the scope of the function (except by copying). Secondly, the pointer passed as a reference must be a local or a temporary - or if isn't, then the function must not call any functions that could have directly or indirectly access to the referenced pointer.

Also consider that if the reference is non-const, then you cannot rely on the implicit conversion (1). Instead, you must create a separate shared pointer of correct type (you can use implicit conversion to create it and pass that. A const reference argument, or a non-reference argument do not have that problem.

> (b) I assume we would be safe memory-wise to cast a std::shared_ptr dog using `reinterpret_cast<std::shared_ptr<Animal>&>(dog)`, right?

Standard-wise, your suggested cast is not safe - it has undefined behaviour. I don't see how assumption (b) follows from the assumption (a).

---

If it's fine to use reference to shared_ptr as an argument in your case, but you cannot avoid increment/decrement of the refcounter due to conversion (derived to base, non-const to const), I recommend using a bare pointer for the argument instead.

Comment: Your suggestion of just using a regular pointer could probably handle the custom copy constructor case I have.  However, one caveat to use a bare pointer is that I cannot modify the original `std::shared_ptr` itself, in the cases where I'm actually really wanting to do that.  For example, I have a generalized `Serialize()` method that needs to alter the variable and the method itself can't be templated because it needs to be virtual.

Comment: You could possibly pass a bare pointer, and return a bare pointer that you then assign to the `shared_ptr` (after down casting, since a function that cannot accept a shared pointer of derived type surely cannot return a derived pointer).

Answer (score 6):

Since its not possible to directly use `static_cast`, `const_cast`, `dynamic_cast` and `reinterpret_cast` on `std::shared_ptr` to retrieve a pointer sharing ownership with the pointer being passed as argument, `std::static_pointer_cast`, `std::const_pointer_cast`, `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` and `std::reinterpret_pointer_cast` functions should be used.

`std::reinterpret_pointer_cast` is not available in C++11 and C++14, as it was only proposed by [N3920](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3920.html) and adopted into Library Fundamentals TS [in February 2014](https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/02/trip-report). However, it can be implemented as follows:

```
template <typename To, typename From>
inline std::shared_ptr<To> reinterpret_pointer_cast(
    std::shared_ptr<From> const & ptr) noexcept
{ return std::shared_ptr<To>(ptr, reinterpret_cast<To *>(ptr.get())); }
```